# Android: How to test in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an app in the market *without* in-app billing. Now the new version should have in-app billing. Of course I am not ready yet and cannot upload the new version to the market, but how can I test and debug my unfinished code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as a first step you need to test it using test requests. This testing is limited but will give you idea if the flow works correct or not.

Second step - real testing. You have to upload your app to Play (NOT publish, just upload), create another account (you can't buy things from yourself) and enable this account in your dev. console. Then you can purchase (for real money) the app and test how well it goes. Of course you can cancel/refund this anytime using your main account.

As a person implementing this in a couple of my apps I can tell you it's a pain.

Refer here for more info:

[In-App Billing reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: what is the strategy that you use for testing your in-app billings. We're at the point that it all works, but we would like to build some unit test around this to make sure it's stable. It seems extremely complicated to test all the response codes from play in a junit test scenario with mock objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the test product id's set up by Google to test your app. Check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,You can use four reserved product IDs to test static in-app billing responses
Secondly,Using a test account and upload you app as a draft,then you can test it using your own product IDs